# Next.js 14 API route in App router returns 401 unauthorized as response

Tags: javascript, next.js, app-router

I am trying to call an API which I defined in my route.ts file in the map folder as shown in the image, however calling it returning a 405 method not allowed response, and I cannot seem to figure out why is that happening even after searching for an hour. I believe that I have the correct folder structure, but I may be missing something, so turned to community for support. Please guide me in fixing this, and if extra information is required please let me know.

Folder structure:

[image: api route folder structure]

Dummy implementation for testing:

```
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
    try {
        return NextResponse.json({ messsage: "Hello World" }, {status: 200});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: error }, {status: 500});
    }
}
```

Here is the response:
[null response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADcxY.png)

EDIT - I am using clerk for my authentication, and below is its middleware implementation:

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
 
export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/"]
});
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```

I searched for it in various articles and other Stack Overflow questions, but could not find any correct answer for this.

Comment: do you have middleware file?

Comment: Yes, @Yilmaz. I have updated my question with that middleware file. Please take a look at it. I am using clerk for the authentication.

Comment: please just paste the code, instead of image. not everyone can load images and it is annoying reading from an image

Comment: Thank you for guiding. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: from which page you make request

Comment: I am making request from this URL - http://localhost:3000/api/map

Comment: Your API route is protected according to the config object you've attached to `authMiddleware`. Are you authenticated when making the request to your API? If not, does adding `"/api"` to the `publicRoutes` array make it accessible when you're not authenticated?

Comment: Hi @G1N, thank you for this suggestion. However, I have already authenticated myself before I access this page, and even after adding "/api" to publicRoutes, it does not work. Moreover, the strange thing is that sometimes it gives me 405 method not allowed response and sometimes it gives me 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Just noticed you're exporting your router function as a default export. I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but what happens when you export it as just the named GET function? (aka `export async function GET()` instead of `export default async function GET()`)

Comment: This solved it! Honestly, I tried this solution before but at that time it didn't work. I may have missed something. Thank you very much for your help, @G1N